# Gridview - Greying out checkboxes once one is checked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm new to all of this code, so please be patient.

On my gridview, I am trying to make it so, once I check on of the checkboxes, the others get greyed out, making it impossible to select another. How would I code this?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using vb, rather than C#.

Edit: Here is the code I want to run.

```
Protected Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 

System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click


Dim TxtbxID As TextBox


  Dim RB As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton


 For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows


 RB = row.FindControl("select")


 If RB.Checked Then


 Me.txtHiddenProblem.Text = row.Cells(3).Text & " on " & row.Cells(5).Text



        TxtbxID = FormView1.FindControl("ProblemTextbox")
        TxtbxID.Text = txtHiddenProblem.Text
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use jQuery, find all instances of the checkbox and disable them.

Comment: ***check on of the checkboxes, the others get greyed out*** doesn't make sense. Please post the code what you have tried so that we know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You are looking for a radiobutton.

Comment: Edit: "Check one of the checkboxes, and the other get greyed out."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=5187857

It has some lines of code which help you determine the particular gridview row the checkbox element was associated with...

```
public void chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkStatus = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkStatus.NamingContainer;
    //other code
}
```

Now all we need to do is when the checkbox element is checked, iterate through the grid, find the checkbox, and disable them if its not the same as the one which caused the event...